# DrawerHeader Image en Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, widget

Alguno sabe como le puedo hacer para que a mi imagen en el DrawerHeader, ignore al menu de notificaciones y se pinte desde el pixel 0,0 del drawer??

```
 Drawer _crearMenu() {
return Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: <Widget>[
      DrawerHeader(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/fondo.jpg'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

[image: Imagen del error app]

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el widget `SafeArea` encima de tu `Scaffold`.

```dart
SafeaArea(
   child: Scaffold( ... ),
);
```

Comment: Excelente Bro, Muchisimas Gracias me funciono perfertamente ::)

Comment: puedes marcar la respuesta como solucionada si te ayudó